# directory problems when using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, hyperlink, directory

I've figured out how Mod rewrite works now however I've come across a new problem.

htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ http://localhost/testblog/index.php?category=$1
```

I now know that this: localhost/testblog/dogs/

is equal to    : localhost/testblog/index.php?category=dogs

however, when i put a link on the index.php file; `<a href="dogs/"> Dogs </a>` that page (localhost/testblog/dogs/) now has the stylesheet prefixed with dogs/ so the stylesheet looks like `localhost/testblog/dogs/stylesheets/style.css`

but when I link with `<a href="index.php?category=dogs"> Dogs </a>` everything works just fine; `localhost/testblog/stylesheets/style.css`

I find it confusing because I thought that they now equaled the same thing using the .htaccess file?

how can i rectify this problem with the prefix?
Hopefully I've explained properly
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is probably more the way you're linking the stylesheet. You're re-writing to /dogs/ and I'm guessing your stylesheet is linked like `<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`. So when you point your browser at /dogs/ it's trying to load a stylesheet in relation to the URL, and it looks like /dogs/ is a folder so it's just appending `stylesheets/style.css` to your current URL. The best bet in my opinion would be to link absolutely to the stylesheet like: `<link href="/testblog/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

Like said Jonathon, the browser compute relative link by appending the href to the url displayed on the adress bar.
To change this, you need to had a base tag

```
<base href="//localhost/testblog">
```

So, your browser will compute your link by adding your href to the base href.